# How to format SharePoint Rest API Data after calling a list item by ID?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I'm using a rest call to pull data from a SharePoint list by item id. I was able to verify it pulls the list items by id, but I'm running into an issue formatting the data.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items(1)",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    cache:false,                
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var items = [];
        $(data.d.results).each(function(){
        items.push('<ul id="' + 'listUL' + '">' + 
        '<li id="' + 'listLI' + '">' + 
        this.Title  +
        '</li>' + 
        '</ul>');
        });
        items.push("</div>");
        $("#listResult").html(items.join(''))
    }
});
</script>

<div id="listResult"></div>
```

Comment: How do you want the data to be formatted? What issue you are facing?

Comment: I'm using chrome to verify the call is pulling data based on the list id. However, when this code or a variant with for html display no results are being displayed in the browser.

If I remove the "(1)" and run the code a collection of data returns to my web page.

In short, I'm one list of data to generate multiple web pages. So, I need to key off list value and pull that row of data for each web page.

Comment: You mean you want to paginate through the items?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to manually create a new page and replace the item id or key off a specific field using an odata call, which would then populate parts of the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting data for multiple items in the list you can change your logic as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var items = [];         
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Modules')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    cache:false,                
    success: function(data){
        $(data.d.results).each(function(){
            items.push(this.Title);
        });

        var html = "<table><tr><td>Title</td></tr><tr><td>" + items[0] + "</td></tr></table>";
        $('#listResult').html(html);
    }
});

var currentIndex = 0;
$('#next').click(function(){
    if(currentIndex < items.length) {
        var html = "<table><tr><td>Title</td></tr><tr><td>" + items[currentIndex] + "</td></tr></table>";
        $('#listResult').html(html);
        currentIndex++;
    }
    else {
        currentIndex = 0;
        var html = "<table><tr><td>Title</td></tr><tr><td>" + items[0] + "</td></tr></table>";
        $('#listResult').html(html);
    }       
});
</script>

<div id="listResult"></div>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next"/>
```

Comment: Amal, 

Your the Man, thx! I had just realized, I simply modifying the $(data.d.results) to something like $(data.d.results[2]) would suffice.

Again, thanks for the learning experience. I'll make some personal notes. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Amal Hashim: The code works but is there way to display 30 or 60 items per view. I only see first item and the next button does not work for me.

Comment: The items array has all values. You can use any jQuery plugin or create code to display accordingly.